# Is there a `notify_one()` queue for `std::condition_variable`s?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

Consider the first thread function and global variables:

```
    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable officer;
    bool firstPlayerIsReady = false;
    bool secondPlayerIsReady = false;
```

---

```
void firstPlayer(){
    constexpr auto doIt = true;
    while(doIt)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock{mut};
        auto toContinue = ring();
        secondPlayerIsReady = true;
        firstPlayerIsReady = false;
        officer.notify_one();   //#1
        if(!toContinue) return;
        officer.wait(lock,[=](){ return firstPlayerIsReady;});
    }
}
```

It calls some ring and ring() returns a continuation condition;
It then updates readiness values for each thread in the next loop;

Consider the next thread:

```
void secondPlayer(){
    constexpr auto doIt = true;
    while(doIt)
    {
        auto period = std::chrono::seconds(5);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(period);

        std::unique_lock lock{mut};   //#2
        officer.wait(lock,[this](){ return secondPlayerIsReady;});
        auto toContinue = ring();
        firstPlayerIsReady = true;
        secondPlayerIsReady = false;
        officer.notify_one();
        if(!toContinue) return;
    }
}
```

This thread wait for 5 seconds and after are locked with wait( ) until the first thread calls the notify_one( );
Further, similar to the first thread.

A priori, the line with #1 tag was executed earlier than the line with #2 tag, therefore the notification was sent earlier than the second thread was locked.
The question is - Is there a notify_one ( ) queue? Otherwise, the notification wasn't sent, obviously.

Comment: Any reason for `constexpr volatile auto doIt`? while that expression is valid, the `volatile` qualifier is useless in the context of your code. secondly you are not actually protecting concurrent accesses to `firstPlayerIsReady`, likewise the other

Comment: @WhiZTiM, thank you, I've fixed it.

Comment: See also: [what if `notify()` is called before `wait()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17562908/4561887)

Answer (score 9):

There is no queue. If one thread calls `notify_one` and there are no other threads waiting it will not do anything.

That's why you have the predicate, in your example

```
officer.wait(lock,[this](){ return secondPlayerIsReady;});
```

So when a thread calls this, if `secondPlayerIsReady` is true, then the thread will not wait at all, but just skip past this line.

So calling `notify_one` too "early" is not a problem as long as the flag is set properly. Just remember that the flag needs to be protected by the mutex when modified.

Comment: Your answer implies that the boolean predicate lambda is tested **before** `wait()` puts the thread to sleep. I always thought it was the other way around: that the `wait()` method put the thread to sleep and then only tested the predicate each time **after** waking up. If the predicate is true, then it returns from the wait function. So, which is it? Is the predicate tested for true *before* sleeping, *after* sleeping, or both?

Comment: If the mutex can be aquired, it can check the condition before going to sleep. I'm not sure if it's required to or if that's an implementation detail, but it's clearly stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: I finally got it! Yaay. :) [I wrote this to put it in my own words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74024531/4561887).

Answer (score 0):

[@super is exactly right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513856/4561887), but I was having a really hard time understanding this concept, so I wanted to put it into my own words and add my own answer as well. Here goes:

### No, `std::condition_variable`s do *not* have an underlying notification queue...

...but that doesn't really matter at all! So long as you use a boolean predicate, an early notification (by a producer) which is sent *before* the consumer hits the `wait()` function will *not* be missed by the consumer!

That is because this call with the lambda function boolean predicate as the 2nd parameter:

```cpp
cv.wait(lock, []() { 
    return sharedData.isNewData; 
});
```

...is **exactly identical** to this `while` loop:

```cpp
while (sharedData.isNewData == false) // OR: `while (!sharedData.isNewData)`
{
    cv.wait(lock);
}
```

...and the while loop's `cv.wait(lock);` line is only called if the predicate is `false` in the first place!

In detail:

There is NOT an underlying notification queue, nor counter, nor boolean flag. Rather, the **boolean predicate** we check *is* the flag! And, it is checked both at the start of the `wait()` function, *before* sleeping, *as well as* at the end of the `wait()` function, after sleeping and each time the thread wakes up. **The `wait()` function *only* sleeps the thread if the predicate starts out `false`, and it only exits the `wait()` function by returning from it when the predicate is `true`.** Look at that `while` loop version just above and this will become perfectly clear.

So, if the producer thread sets a shared predicate to `true`, and then sends a `my_condition_variable.notify_one()` call, if the consumer thread is not *already* waiting, it does *not* receive that notification. BUT, it doesn't really matter! So long as the consumer thread is either using the 2-parameter `wait()` call (with the 2nd parameter being a boolean predicate), OR using the `while` loop predicate-checking technique, then once the consumer thread hits the `wait()` call (or while loop), the predicate will be seen as being `true`, and the whole while block and waiting sleep will be skipped entirely, and the consumer will go ahead and run instantly *as though* it *had* received the `notify_one()` notification while waiting! When the predicate is used, the end result is the same *as though* the condition variable did have an underlying notification queue (or flag) of length one.

See:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait - it states that this templated function:

   > ```cpp
   > template< class Predicate >
   > void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate stop_waiting );
   > ```

   is:

   > Equivalent to
   >
   > ```cpp
   > while (!stop_waiting()) {
   >     wait(lock);
   > }
   > ```
2. Answer by [@super](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513856/4561887), who set me on the right track to finally understand this myself

### See also

1. I documented the above information, with detailed full examples of `std::condition_variable` and how to use it in a producer-consumer thread-safe queue in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [std_mutex_vs_std_lock_guard_vs_std_unique_lock_vs_std_scoped_lock_README.md](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/std_mutex_vs_std_lock_guard_vs_std_unique_lock_vs_std_scoped_lock_README.md), and on my personal website here: https://gabrielstaples.com/cpp-mutexes-and-locks/.