# Not able to set conditional Variable

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

in the below code I am waiting inside function `waitingForWork()` on a condition variable, but`doTheCleanUp()` is never called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>          // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable


std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool stop=false;

void stopTheWait()
{
    sleep(5);
    printf("stopping the wait.. \n\n");
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    stop = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}

void doTheCleanUp()/* is never called*/ {
    printf("clean up... \n\n");
}

void waitingForWork(){
    printf("wait for ever... \n\n");

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck, []{ return stop;});
    doTheCleanUp();
    printf("clean Up Done, now end wait... \n\n");
}


int main()
{
    printf("in main... \n");
   
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

   std::thread t1(stopTheWait);
   
   waitingForWork();
   
   printf("exiting main...\n");
   sleep(1);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: There are C++ versions of those C headers named `cstdio`, `cstdlib` and `csignal`. Prefer using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main()` is locking the `std::mutex` and then calling `waitingForWork()` in the same thread, which tries to lock the `std::mutex` again.  [This is **undefined behavior**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> If `lock` is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, *the behavior is undefined*: for example, *the program may deadlock*. An implementation that can detect the invalid usage is encouraged to throw a `std::system_error` with error condition `resource_deadlock_would_occur` instead of deadlocking.

There is no good reason for `main()` to obtain that initial lock, get rid of it:

```cpp
int main()
{
    printf("in main... \n");
   
   //std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); // <-- HERE

   std::thread t1(stopTheWait);
   
   waitingForWork();
   
   printf("exiting main...\n");
   sleep(1);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Note that in general, if you must lock a mutex multiple times in the same thread, you need to use [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) instead:

> A calling thread owns a `recursive_mutex` for a period of time that starts when it successfully calls either `lock` or `try_lock`. **During this period, the thread may make additional calls to `lock` or `try_lock`.** The period of ownership ends when the thread makes a matching number of calls to `unlock`.

---

Also note that you need to call `t1.join()` or `t1.detach()` before `t1` goes out of scope and is destroyed, otherwise its [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) will abortively terminate the calling process:

> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), [`std::terminate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is called.

Comment: The C++20 [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) that auto-joins may be worth mentioning as an alternative.

Comment: The main thread must get the lock (before the thread) and keep it until it calls wait. Otherwise the thread may reach notify_all first and then the main thread will be stuck.

Comment: [what if notify() is called before wait()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562908/).  If `main()` needs to lock the mutex while creating the `thread`, then it needs to unlock the mutex before calling `waitingForWork()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug here:

```
void waitingForWork(){
    printf("wait for ever... \n\n");

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);         // This lock is bad.
                                                   // you already locked the
                                                   // mutex in main.
                                                   //
                                                   // locking it again is UB

    cv.wait(lck, []{ return stop;});               // Once you enter wait()
                                                   // lock will be released
                                                   // until you are notified.
    doTheCleanUp();
    printf("clean Up Done, now end wait... \n\n");
}
```